# Flink: the result of SocketWindowCount example isn't what I expected

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

I am new to flink. I follow the quickstart on the flink website and deploy flink on a single machine. After I do "./bin/flink run examples/streaming/SocketWindowWordCount.jar --port 9000" and enter the words as the website described, I get the result:[final result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pnyg6.png)

It seems that the program didn't do the reduce,I just want to know why? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The program did do a reduce, but not fully, because your input must have fallen into two different 5 second windows. That's why the 4 instances of ipsum where reported as 1 + 3 -- the first one fell into one window, and the other 3 into another window (along with the "bye").

Flink's window boundaries are based on alignment with the clock. So if your input events occurred between 14:00:04 and 14:00:08, for example, they would fall into two 5 second windows -- one for 14:00:00 - 14:00:04.999 and another for 14:00:05 - 14:00:09.999 -- even though all of your events fit into a single interval that's only 4 seconds long.

If you try again, you can expect to see similar, but probably different results. That's a consequence of doing windowed analytics based on "processing time". If you want your applications to get repeatable results, you should plan on using "[event time](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.6/dev/event_time.html)" analytics instead (where the timestamps are based on when the events occurred, rather than when they were processed).